# Unable to format Vue Datepicker value into date format in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am unable to convert vue datepicker value in laravel model.
When i convert it returns false, does timezone effects this somehow ?
I am working in +5 GMT.

That's how i am converting.

```
'period_thru' => date_format(date_create($data['period_thru']), 'Y-m-d' ),
```

Comment: what is the content of $data['period_thru'] ?

Comment: it's a date i am getting from vue-datepicker through request.
It's format is : Thu Feb 04 2021 10:09:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

Comment: I test this, and it works :O.
echo date_format(date_create("Thu Feb 04 2021 10:09:23 GMT+0500"), 'Y-m-d' ); // 2021-02-04

Comment: Maybe you should remove this string " (Pakistan Standard Time) "